# Solving a complex number equation with both $z$ and its conjugate $\bar z$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

> Determine all possible values of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy the equation $4z = \overline{z}^2$.
>
> Where $\overline{z}$ represents the complex conjugate.
>
> (Hint: There are $4$ solutions.)

#### Observations

If we had $4z=z^2$, that would be an easy quadratic equation, with solutions $0,4$.

And if it was $4\bar z = \bar z^2$, then after substitution $\zeta=\bar z$ we have a quadratic equation again.

But this equation has  both $z$ and $\bar z$. I'm not sure how to solve these types of problems. Any tips or how to do these would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $z=a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then your equation says:
$$4(a+bi)=(a-bi)^2.$$
Which means that
$$4a+4bi=(a^2-b^2)-2abi.$$
Now the above equality of complex numbers is a system of equations of real numbers:
$$\begin{cases}
4a=a^2-b^2\\
4b=-2ab
\end{cases}.$$
Solve it and you'll find the solutions.

Comment: Solving the above system I got the $4$ solutions: $z=-2\pm\sqrt{12}i$, $z=0$, or $z=4$.

Comment: I got the first two solutions, but how did you get z=0 or z=4?

Comment: Ops nevermind i got it thanks a lot!

Comment: Wops again, i actually don't get how you got those, explanation please!

Comment: Consider the two cases: $b\neq 0$ or $b=0$. In the first case, the second equation implies that $a=-2$, substituting that into the first equation you get $b=\pm\sqrt{12}$. In the second case, $b=0$, the first equation implies $a^2-4a=0$ whence $a=0$ or $a=4$.

Comment: @user136088, it is just a way to make sure that we cover all options. Any (real) number is either $0$ or is not $0$, therefore if you consider both these cases, you have covered all options for $b$.

Comment: I got it now thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use the polar representation $z = r e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is the obvious solution $z=0$. From now on, assume $z\ne 0$. Taking norms, we find that $|z|=4$. Let $z=4e^{i\theta}$. Then we want $e^{i\theta}=e^{-2i\theta}$. We leave the rest to you.